# Microsoft Word Macro VB

Tags: vba, search, replace, ms-word

Need some help here...

I need something that can delete only the 9 digit (or 6-9 digits only), then replace all spaces and return carraige with "," Comma

**N6FDT1485** 355395112146 355395112146 35539511210 355395112153 35539511214 35539511210 355395112147 355395112100 3553951121189 355395112100

**N6FDC4347** 35545111128 355451111269 355451111263 355451111250 355451111260 355451111260 355451111258 355451111258576 3554511112618 355451111151

so it comes out like below;

355395112146,355395112146,35539511210,355395112153,35539511214,35539511210,355395112147,35539511210, 355395112189,355395112100,35545111128,355451111269,35545111126,35545111250,355451111260,35545111160, 355451111258,355451111258,35545111126,355451111151

I have using this code below, but I still have to manually delete N6FDC4347, N6FDT1485 or variants of those 9 digits first before I run the code..

```
Sub document_cleanup()

'

' document_cleanup Macro

' Remove trailing spaces and double spaces, tabs, and Enter keys

'

Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting

Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

' Remove trailing spaces from a paragraph

With Selection.Find

.Text = "^w^v"

.Replacement.Text = "^v"

.Forward = True

End With

Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

' Remove double spaces

With Selection.Find

.Text = " "

.Replacement.Text = ","

End With

Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

' Remove double tabs

With Selection.Find

.Text = "^t^t"

.Replacement.Text = " ^t"

End With

Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

' Remove double Enter keys (blank paragraphs)

With Selection.Find

.Text = "^p"

.Replacement.Text = ""

End With

Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

End Sub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something other than repetition of the information already in the tags. The title should describe the problem you're having or question you're asking, and be clear enough to have meaning to a future user of this site scanning a list of search results looking for a solution to their problem. All you've done is repeat the tags.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of your code serves no obvious purpose - perhaps because you haven't fully described the data you're starting with or what the expected outcome is. That said, it would seem you could use:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Forward = True
    .Format = False
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .Text = "^w"
    .Replacement.Text = " "
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Text = "[ ^013]{2,}"
    .Replacement.Text = ",^p"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "[A-Z][0-9][A-Z0-9]{7} "
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "([0-9]{5}) ([0-9]{5})"
    .Replacement.Text = "\1,\2"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: covert the following ;

Comment: I need to delete all or anything that tag info that contains 9 digits or letters, then replace all SPACE with comma's.

Comment: Which is what the code I posted does... If you're not getting the results you need, update your problem description to make it clearer. As I said, «A lot of your code serves no obvious purpose - perhaps because you haven't fully described the data you're starting with or what the expected outcome is».